# how to create horizontal strait graph in d3 from left to right according to the order of the nodes

Tags: d3.js

I want to create a simple d3 horizontal strait graph.

It would contain nodes, links and lines for each link.

How can I define correctly coordinates of nodes/ edges in the tick to achieve it (without manually setting the coordinates).

Do I need to do some pre calculation before?

I basically want the 1st node to appear on the far left and the last node in the chain (graph) (it's a striat line) to appear on the far right of the chain (graph).

How can I determine the order of the nodes in the graph to align them.

**Update**

here's the fiddle I reached so far:

here i just hard coded the y axis, which i want dynamically.

and my nodes are also not in order.

```
  const nodes = [
  { id: 'A' },
  { id: 'B' },
  { id: 'C' },
];

const edges = [
  { source: 'A', target: 'B' },
  { source: 'B', target: 'C' },
];

const svg = d3.select("svg");

// Create arrowhead marker
svg.append('defs').append('marker')
    .attr('id', 'arrowhead')
    .attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10')
    .attr('refX', 15)
    .attr('refY', 0)
    .attr('orient', 'auto')
    .attr('markerWidth', 10)
    .attr('markerHeight', 10)
    .attr('xoverflow', 'visible')
    .append('svg:path')
    .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
    .attr('fill', '#ccc')
    .style('stroke','none');

const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(edges).id(d => d.id).distance(150))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
    .force("y", d3.forceY(200))
    .force("x", d3.forceX(200));
    //.force("center", d3.forceCenter(400, 200));

const link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(edges)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)');

const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 20);

simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => 20)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => 20);

    node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => 20);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g87s23L5/3/

Ideally I'm looking for a way to use the built-in forces of d3

Comment: Can you share what have you done previously?

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan - I don't have a workable version. I just don't know how to align the nodes according to a specific order

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan - added fiddle

Comment: @HeinzSiahaan - thank you!
I have 2 Qs. 1. how can i tell that the circles in your example are in order? they all look the same. 2. where is the order logic. i just see you pass i parameter?
I'm using v7 btw.

Comment: I just noticed that for the version to work in the right order, it takes the nodes according to their order defined in the begning so if i would to put node B first, it would put him first in the line even though he's 2nd.
. so does that mean I have to arrange the nodes in the correct order BEFORE?

Comment: As far as I know, the order of nodes and edges should be in order. We can put B first on order node (ex: B,A,C), and on edge list we can fill B->A, A->C and it will be ordered too. Maybe needs different approach to get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create simulation, I've adjusted the force("x", ...) to position the nodes based on their index. This will ensure that the nodes appear in the order from left to right.

This is the fixed code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>D3 Horizontal Straight Graph</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .node {
      fill: #3498db;
      stroke: #2980b9;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      cursor: pointer;
      marker-end: url(#arrowhead); /* Add arrowhead to links */

.line {
  stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <svg width="800" height="400"></svg>
  <script>
     const nodes = [
      { id: 'A' },
      { id: 'B' },
      { id: 'C' },
    ];

    const edges = [
      { source: 'A', target: 'B' },
      { source: 'B', target: 'C' },
    ];

const svg = d3.select("svg");

    // Create arrowhead marker
    svg.append('defs').append('marker')
        .attr('id', 'arrowhead')
        .attr('viewBox', '-0 -5 10 10')
        .attr('refX', 15)
        .attr('refY', 0)
        .attr('orient', 'auto')
        .attr('markerWidth', 10)
        .attr('markerHeight', 10)
        .attr('xoverflow', 'visible')
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
        .attr('fill', '#ccc')
        .style('stroke','none');

    const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
        .force("link", d3.forceLink(edges).id(d => d.id).distance(150))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-100))
        .force("y", d3.forceY(200))
        .force("x", d3.forceX((d, i) => i * 200)); // Position nodes based on index

    const link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(edges)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)');

    const node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", 20);

    simulation.on("tick", () => {
        link.attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
            .attr("y1", d => 50)// you can adjust y axis to make it viewable
            .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
            .attr("y2", d => 50);// you can adjust y axis to make it viewable

        node.attr("cx", d => d.x)
            .attr("cy", d => 50);// you can adjust y axis to make it viewable
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check on my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/heinzmdsiahaan/kd5za0ur/4/)